# Column only checks the first item. Access database

Tags: c#, database, windows, forms, ms-access

I got this windows forms that checks if the username that the user digit on the text box is valid. But only the first item on the column is checked. Example: if i digit "john" he checks that is true, because john is the first
string on the column, but if i digit "Stella" that is the second string on the column in the same database the program returns false.

[I have to upload the img because i got problems when i tried to post the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7igH.png)

Comment: As far as I can tell you're not even trying to check the other rows. You need to loop through them, until `Read()` returns `false`. And you can post the code just fine. Just remember to click the `{}` button to format it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not looping through the result set. You need to read all the records one by one and implement the logic for each record.

Do something like this :

```
        if (usrname.HasRows)
        {
            while (usrname.Read())
            {
                 if (usrname.GetString(0) == userdigtext){
                     // messagebox here for success
                 }
                 else {
                     // messagebox here for failure
                 }
            }
        }
```

Comment: No worries mate. Also don't forget to close the reader... 
        usrname.Close();